# How to model Paxos in TLA+ Toolbox?

Tags: modeling, paxos, tla+

I try to model Paxos ([Paxos example](https://tlaplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/Paxos/README)) in TLA+ Toolbox ([toolbox](https://tla.msr-inria.inria.fr/tlaps/content/Download/Binaries.html)). What numbers should I put in the model to make it work? Or are there other ways a confirmation of this algorithm in this toolbox?

Base on this code:

```
CONSTANT Value,     \* The set of choosable values.
     Acceptor,  \* A set of processes that will choose a value.
     Quorum     \* The set of "quorums", where a quorum" is a 
                \*   "large enough" set of acceptors
```

I try numbers like this:

Acceptor <- [11,12,13,14,15];

Quorum <- [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19];

Value <- [0,1];

but I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your model:

1. For specifying a set, you should use curly braces, so Acceptor <- {11,12,13,14,15}.
2. Quorum should be a set of sets of acceptors, e.g. Quorum <- {{11,12,13},{12,13,14}}.